# Not able to complete AWS CLI on my mac

Tags: macos, command-line, mac, amazon-web-services

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/docutils'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I have Python 2.7 and macOS Mojave (V: 10.14.5) and I'm not entirely sure why I cannot install the AWS CLI onto my computer, could someone give me some suggestions/advice?

(Should I just throw my mac away? jk dont reply to that)

Comment: How were you attempting to install it? AWS provides several options.

Comment: Hey, so I was trying to install the AWS CLI onto my computer using pip, but it wouldn't work